# copy values from different columns based on conditions (r code)

Tags: r, dataframe

[image]

I have data like one in the picture where there are two columns (Cday,Dday) with some missing values.
There can't be a row where there are values for both columns; there's a value on either one column or the other or in neither.

I want to create the column "new" that has copied values from whichever column there was a number.
Really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

Since no row has a value for both, you can just sum up the two existing columns. Assume your dataframe is called `df`.

```
df$'new' = rowSums(df[,2:3], na.rm=T)
```

This will sum the rows, removing NAs and should give you what you want. (Note: you may need to adjust column numbering if you have more columns than what you've shown).

Answer (score 0):

The `dplyr` package has the `coalesce` function.

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(id=1:8, Cday=c(1,2,NA,NA,3,NA,2,NA), Dday=c(NA,NA,NA,3,NA,2,NA,1))
new <- df %>% mutate(new = coalesce(Dday, Cday, na.rm=T))
new
#  id Cday Dday new
#1  1    1   NA   1
#2  2    2   NA   2
#3  3   NA   NA  NA
#4  4   NA    3   3
#5  5    3   NA   3
#6  6   NA    2   2
#7  7    2   NA   2
#8  8   NA    1   1
```